# Constant charge density and magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, maxwell-equations

Suppose we have an arbitrary number of point charges in a vacuum, described by a constant charge density $\rho$. Can they be the sources of a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$? My intuition is that they can't, but how can I show it?

I'm aware of Maxwell's equations, but does the fact that $\rho$ is constant imply that $\mathbf{E}$ is static? In turn, does that mean that $\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=0$? If so, what can we say about $\mathbf{B}$? I'm still confused about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constant charge density does not imply a zero magnetic field. Even considering a set of isolated charges, suppose they were (mechanically) moved along a circular path. The charge density could remain the same but there would be a current flow. The curl of the magnetic field produced would be $\mu_0 \vec{J}$, where $\vec{J}$ is the current density.

If the charge density is static, all you can say (from the equation of charge continuity) is that the divergence $\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = 0$. This also does not imply time-independence. For instance, you could speed up the circular motion of the charges to get a larger current density and a larger magnetic field.

If you can have a time-dependent magnetic field then you will also get a time-dependent electric field. The time-independence of $\rho$ only tells you that the divergence of the electric field is time-independent.

Comment: So we know nothing at all about $\mathbf{B}$, just from the fact that $\rho$ is constant?

Comment: Thought experiment. Place a box in the Earth's magnetic field. Fill the box with (static) charges. How does that change the magnetic field in the box? Subject the interior of the box to a changing magnetic field - the charges stay static. Knowing what $\rho$ is cannot lead to a description of the magnetic field in the box.